Error when inserting data into GridDB time-series container: "RowSet not initialized"
I'm developing a Java application using GridDB to handle time-series data. My goal is to insert records into a time-series container, but I keep encountering an error when trying to retrieve the data. Specifically, I'm getting a GSException: RowSet not initialized error when I attempt to fetch rows after inserting data.
Here’s the code I'm using:
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;

public class GridDBTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GSException {
        GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
        GridStore store = factory.getGridStore("host=127.0.0.1;port=10001;clusterName=myCluster;user=admin;password=admin");

        // Define time-series container with timestamp and value columns
        ContainerInfo containerInfo = new ContainerInfo();
        containerInfo.setType(ContainerType.TIME_SERIES);
        containerInfo.setRowKeyAssigned(true);
        containerInfo.setColumnInfoList(List.of(
            new ColumnInfo("timestamp", GSType.TIMESTAMP),
            new ColumnInfo("value", GSType.DOUBLE)
        ));
        TimeSeries<?> timeSeries = store.putTimeSeries("SampleData", containerInfo, true);

        // Insert data
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Date timestamp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (i * 1000L));
            Row row = timeSeries.createRow();
            row.setTimestamp(0, timestamp);
            row.setDouble(1, Math.random() * 100);
            timeSeries.put(timestamp, row);
        }

        // Attempt to retrieve data
        RowSet<?> rs = timeSeries.query(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 60000), new Date()).fetch();
        while (rs.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rs.next();
            System.out.println("Timestamp: " + row.getTimestamp(0) + ", Value: " + row.getDouble(1));
        }

        store.close();
    }
}

Error Message:
Exception in thread "main" com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSException: RowSet not initialized
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowSetImpl.hasNext(RowSetImpl.java:48)
    ...


Troubleshooting Steps Tried:
Verified the connection details (host, port, clusterName, etc.) and confirmed they’re correct.
Ensured that the container creation step runs without errors.
Checked if fetch() is needed immediately after the query() method to initialize the RowSet.
Despite these steps, I still get the same error. Am I missing something in the query handling, or could this be due to a configuration issue in GridDB? Any suggestions would be helpful!
